# Hiding/Showing sections comparing ids to classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two sections and on the first section it should only show the section relevant to the second one. I am trying to compare ids of the second set of elements to the classes of the first set.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.first-sub').hide();
  
  $('.second-sub a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    
    $(this).hasClass(id).show();
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first-section">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>This is the intro section</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-one">
    <p>This is section one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-two">
    <p>This is section two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-three">
    <p>This is section three</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-section">
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-one">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it following way.

JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.first-sub').hide();

  $('.second-sub a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("div.first-section ."+id).show();
  });

});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="first-section">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>This is the intro section</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-one">
    <p>This is section one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-two">
    <p>This is section two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-three">
    <p>This is section three</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-section">
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-one">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section two</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-three">Show Section three</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YKsKQK3SpjsgA6XvKalc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

There's no hasId method for checking if element has id. Use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is) instead:

```
$(this).is(id).show();
```

But the above method won't work. Because is method returns boolean and you can't have a method. So, you need to do like this:

```
if($(this).is(id)){
   $(this).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter elements by class, [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass) return a jQuery object so calling [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show) on it will throw an error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $subs = $('.first-sub').hide();

  $('.second-sub a').click(function() {
    $subs.filter('.' + this.id).show().siblings('.first-sub').hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first-section">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>This is the intro section</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-one">
    <p>This is section one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-two">
    <p>This is section two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-three">
    <p>This is section three</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-section">
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-one">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section two</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-three">Show Section three</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `".first-section ." + this.id` as selector within `click` event to call `.show()` on , chaining `.siblings().hide()` to hide siblings of selected element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.first-sub').hide();
  
  $('.second-sub a').click(function() {
    
    $(".first-section ." + this.id).show()
    .siblings().hide();
  });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first-section">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>This is the intro section</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-one">
    <p>This is section one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-two">
    <p>This is section two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-three">
    <p>This is section three</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-section">
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-one">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section Two</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-three">Show Section Three</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.first-sub').hide();
  $('.second-sub a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var element=".first-section .first-sub."+id+"";       
       $('.first-sub').hide();
      $(element).fadeIn("slow");
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="first-section">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>This is the intro section</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-one">
    <p>This is section one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-two">
    <p>This is section two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="first-sub section-three">
    <p>This is section three</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-section">
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-one">Show Section One</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section one</a>
  </div>
  <div class="second-sub">
    <a href="#" id="section-two">Show Section one</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[js Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/9an6vx0r/)